# Can I edit in the msg.sender value for the called contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, opcode

let's assume following solidity contracts:

```
 contract EntryPointContract {

    address one = '0x...';
    address two = '0x...';
    address delegateContract;

    constructor(address _delegateContract) {
        delegateContract = _delegateContract;
    }
 
    function test() public returns(bool) {

        (bool success,) = delegateContract.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("checkSender()"));
        return success
    }

}

contract DelegateContract {

    function checkSender() public {
        msgs = msg.sender;
    }
    
}
```

Can I modify the **EntryPointContract**  in some way that i will get **address one** value from EntryPointContract as **msg.sender** in **DelegateContract** ?
Is it doable with assembly or opcodes for example or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solidity, it is not possible to directly set `msg.sender` in the called contract (`DelegateContract`) to a specific address like `address one` from `EntryPointContract`. The `msg.sender` is determined by the caller of the contract, and it cannot be manipulated within the contract itself.

The `msg.sender` in `DelegateContract` will always be the address of the contract or external entity that calls the `checkSender()` function. You cannot change this behavior through assembly, opcodes, or any other means within the Solidity code.

If you need to pass specific information to `DelegateContract` that you want to be treated as the sender, you would need to pass it as an argument to a function in `DelegateContract`. For example:

```
contract EntryPointContract {
    address one = '0x...';
    address delegateContract;

    constructor(address _delegateContract) {
        delegateContract = _delegateContract;
    }
 
    function test() public returns(bool) {
        bool success = DelegateContract(delegateContract).checkSender(one);
        return success;
    }
}

contract DelegateContract {
    address public sender;

    function checkSender(address specificSender) public {
        sender = specificSender;
    }
}
```

In this modified example, the `test()` function of `EntryPointContract` explicitly passes the desired sender address (`one`) to the `checkSender()` function in `DelegateContract`.

Comment: for exmaple  what if DelagateContract is already deployed and  I need somehow pass 'address one' in msg.sender?

Comment: In this case, if the contract is upgradable, the code can be changed and the new method implemented, otherwise it cannot be done and it must be redeployed.

Comment: Read this link, maybe it can give you an idea: https://soliditydeveloper.com/erc20-permit